# How to use unicode in URL in biblatex using xelatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber, unicode

Here's an example document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{extreport}    
\usepackage[style=gost-numeric,defernumbers]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{t.bib}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[cm-default]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

Some text with unicode here\cite{t}. Немного текста в юникоде.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

In `t.bib` I have:

```
@online{t,
title = {Утечка памяти},
media = {eresource},
language = {russian},
url = {https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Утечка\_памяти}
}
```

I suppose everything to be in unicode, but the URL doesn't support it and looks bad. Is there any way to use unicode in URL?
[image]

Comment: I don't think that is currently possible to avoid that biber escapes the non-ascii parts of the url. You would have to put the text in some normal verbatim field and change the style to use it.

Comment: \usepackage{hyperref} might work.

Comment: @pseudoAJ, no, it doesn't help

Comment: If you are using XeLaTeX, don't load `inputenc`!

Comment: That is the real url the internet uses. Your browser just displays it a bit more friendly. I wouldn't care too much about it.

Comment: I absolutely agree with Johannes here. When I opened the link from your `.bib` thre directky, I could see firefox see it convert to the encoding you see in the output and then back to the more easy-on-the-eye output you want. Please note that the backslash before the underscore is superfluous, you want `url = {https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Утечка_памяти}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@UlrikeFischer is correct - biber only has one field to work with and so chooses the encoded format for maximum compatibility. You could easily use a sourcemap to copy to another verbatim field (like `verba`) and use that as the printable version whilst keeping `url` for the hyperref link. This would need a minor style change but should be relatively easy (make sure `hyperref` is loaded):

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=url]
      \step[fieldset=verba, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\href{#1}{\thefield{verba}}}
```

Comment: Now there are no linebreaks in URLs: [screenshot](https://pp.vk.me/c625529/v625529188/42cd9/nf9dZBObfzk.jpg)

Comment: Did you load `hyperref` with `breaklinks = true`?

Comment: @hant0508: Use \nolinkurl: `\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\href{#1}{\nolinkurl{\thefield{verba}}}}`